# JTable completely remove focus

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to completely remove the focus form the table (rows and cells) when clicking the underlying scroll pane. There shall be no selection anymore like before clicking anything within the TableModel.

See [this GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQYxD.jpg) as an example of the current problem.

The code I currently use in a mousePressed event listener:

```
private void tableScrollPaneMousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    TableUtils.deselectAll(dataTable);
}

// In TableUtils:

/**
 * Clear all selections
 * @param table
 */
public static void deselectAll(JTable table) {
    if (table.isEditing()) {
        table.removeEditor();
    }
    table.clearSelection();
}
```

**EDIT:**

As requested here is a **runnable example**. Same issue: When clicking the table a row gets selected. When clicking the underlying panel it removes all selections but the "focus" / "cursor" is still available on the table.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JTable table;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(600, 450));
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(570, 450));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{0, 0};
        gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{1.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        GridBagConstraints gbc_scrollPane = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc_scrollPane.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridx = 0;
        gbc_scrollPane.gridy = 0;
        frame.getContentPane().add(scrollPane, gbc_scrollPane);

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(
            new Object[][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null, null},
            },
            new String[] {
                "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column", "New column"
            }
        ));

        scrollPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                if (table.isEditing()) {
                    table.removeEditor();
                }
                table.clearSelection();
            }
        });

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `tableScrollPaneMousePressed` get called ?

Comment: Yes it does (as you see it fires the ```table.clearSelection();```)

Comment: So what is your question ?

Comment: ```table.clearSelection();``` causes the row selection to vanish.

Comment: I want to get rid of all selection, so that the white box I circle at the end (focus on cell something like that) is also removed.

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: Nope does not help, give me a second for runnable example code.

Comment: @MadProgrammer see the edit for a simple runnable example. It should by copy paste into any IDE.

Comment: It has to do with the `MouseListener` on the `JScrollPane`, why, I have no idea, but the `JScrollPane` does some funky image blitting to improve it's performance

Comment: What's your issue with the table having focus?

Comment: there is possble to dispatch mouse, mousemotion and key events by using SwingUtilities or just to consume(I don't recomend)

Comment: whats reason if (table.isEditing()) {  == to override isCellEditable(false) in model, then you can't to fire, convet, dispatch anytthing, nowhere

Comment: Okay thanks so far, as you asked why this concerns me --> It does not work like it "should" regarding UX and does not look well / right either. It might not be a must but it concerns me (I think everybody has his OCD at some points ;) ). The thing is, that if you hover above a JMenu the "focus" goes away until you get back to the table....

Comment: I guess my UX differs from yours =), I have no problem with that behaviour. I also don't know of any programs that have the behaviour you want.

Comment: **Workaround** You could have an invisible component call grabFocus()